# Create a certificate with a private key

Tags: sql-server

Reading this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48752/7820) I have a question about it:

How can I create a certificate with a private key in my app database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CREATE CERTIFICATE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187798.aspx), see the first example Creating a self-signed certificate:

```
use <mydb>;
go

CREATE CERTIFICATE Shipping04 
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mysecretpassword'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Used to signed procedure usp_foo', 
   EXPIRY_DATE = '20181231';
GO
```

When you sign with it you need to specify again the password:

```
ADD SIGNATURE TO [usp_foo]
  BY CERTIFICATE <certname> WITH PASSWORD 'mysecretpassword';
```

See [Signing an activated procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/) for an example.